# Displaying nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently working on a quiz at the moment in Javascript where the question and answers are in a nested JSON data structure. My structure looks something like this:

```
var quizContent = [
  {
    "question": "Why is the sky blue?",
    "answers": [
      { "answer": "Blue light is scattered in all directions by the tiny molecules of air in Earth's atmosphere." },
      { "answer": "Idk dude" },
      { "answer": "google.com" },
      { "answer": "It just is." }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Why did the chicken cross the road?",
    "answers": [
      { "answer": "To get to the other side." },
      { "answer": "Obama amiriteeee" },
      { "answer": "To escape genocide. "},
      { "answer": "To find itself." }
    ]
  }
]
```

Obviously this is a somewhat comical approach, but I'm a little stuck on the logic of getting the values for the questions followed by the available answers.

For now I'll just show the progress through log console.log statements.

```
for (var i = 0; i < quizContent.length; i++){
  var obj = quizContent[i];
  for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  }
}
```

With this seems to get sort of what I need but eventually I'll need to go a bit further and individually put the questions in header tags as well as the answers in list items so having that control is important.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your question? Its a good post but I can't really tell what you're asking.

Comment: @Feathercrown apologies for any confusion with my phrasing. Essentially I'm looking to individually get each question and it's available answers.

Comment: @thegloriouspast Ok, I see now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to present your questions and answers on the page, this sort of code will create something that will go through your object and allow participants to select a response:

```js
var quizContent = [
  {
    "question": "Why is the sky blue?",
    
    // note lack of "answer" key for each answer.    
    "answers": [
      "Blue light is scattered in all directions by the tiny molecules of air in Earth's atmosphere.",
      "Idk dude", 
      "google.com", 
      "It just is."
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Why did the chicken cross the road?",
    "answers": [ 
      "To get to the other side.", 
      "Obama amiriteeee", 
      "To escape genocide. ", 
      "To find itself."
    ]
  }
];

form_div_html = '';
quizContent.forEach(function(row,index){
  form_div_html += "<h1>"+row.question+"</h1>";
  row.answers.forEach(function(answer){
    form_div_html += "<label><input type='radio' name='question_"+index+"' value='"+answer+"'>"+answer+"</label><br>";
  });
  form_div_html += "<br>";
});
document.getElementById("form_div").innerHTML = form_div_html;
```

```html
<div id="form_div"></div>
```

I've edited the structure of your object to make it easier to loop through. Also, note that using labels gives you user the flexibility of clicking on the radio button, or any of the text within the label.

Comment: Nice, although I'd put the radio button before the text.

Comment: ha ha! I was just doing that as you said it

Comment: Ah, much better. ;)

Comment: I like this answer and thanks for the clarity on the advantage of radio buttons/labels. The only thing I'm wondering about is that when implementing your solution, the question is fine, however, the answers seem to output "[object Object]"? Any thoughts?

Comment: I think that's because I changed my structure of the json object. Try copying out the whole of my var quizcontent and compare with your original, and that might show the differences.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, overlooked that. Is there any advantage of structuring it that way? Or is that just personal preference?

Comment: I think the advantage is that you need less code to refer to each answer. If there's a reason why you need to have "answer" for each answer, then it is potentially a problem to do it the way I have. For example, in your case you might want each answer to include: "answer: 'text for your answer" and "correct_answer: true". Shall I adjust my answer to accomodate that?

Comment: This is a pretty low level quiz so that would be unnecessary but thank you for the offer! I don't disagree with you I was just curious about your decision to restructure.

Comment: If I wanted to increment these questions/answers. Say display them in steps. First question is display: block, while the others are display none. In simplest fashion, I was thinking of using jQuery's show() and hide() but I'm slightly confused with how to proceed with that. There would be a next and previous button that would allow you to move on to the next question or step backward if necessary. How would you go about that using your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164992/discussion-between-anthony-haffey-and-thelgloriouspast).

Answer (score 1):

The loop should be like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < quizContent.length; i++){
  var obj = quizContent[i];
  var question = obj.question;
  console.log(`Question #${i}: ${question}`);
  for (var j in obj.answers) {
    var answer = obj.answers[i].answer;
    console.log(`Answer #${j}: ${answer}`);
  }
}
```

In your actual code you would probably display this as nested HTML lists or a `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` function along with jQuery to build your quiz.

```js
var quizContent = [
  {
    "question": "Why is the sky blue?",
    "answers": [
      { "answer": "Blue light is scattered in all directions by the tiny molecules of air in Earth's atmosphere." },
      { "answer": "Idk dude" },
      { "answer": "google.com" },
      { "answer": "It just is." }
    ]
  },
  {
    "question": "Why did the chicken cross the road?",
    "answers": [
      { "answer": "To get to the other side." },
      { "answer": "Obama amiriteeee" },
      { "answer": "To escape genocide. "},
      { "answer": "To find itself." }
    ]
  }
];

var $quiz = $('#quiz');
quizContent.forEach((q, i) => {
  var question = q.question;
  var answers = q.answers;
  
  var $qelem = $(`<h2>#${i + 1} ${question}</h2>`);
  $quiz.append($qelem);
  
    answers.forEach((a, j) => {
      $quiz.append($(`<li>${i + 1}.${j + 1} ${a.answer}</li>`));
    });
  
  $quiz.append($('hr'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='quiz'>
<div>
```